# Creating Amazon Signaure V4 for Froala Image editor with Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding, froala

I am following this guide https://gist.github.com/stefanneculai/deed108fad534d0db3ff to creating an Amazon Signature.

```
  def getSignatureKey
    kDate    = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', 'AWS4' + Figaro.env.aws_secret_access_key, Time.zone.now.utc.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
    kRegion  = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kDate, 'us-west-2')
    kService = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kRegion, 's3')
    kSigning = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kService, 'aws4_request')
    kSigning
  end
```

I am using the froala gem for rails and using the `imageUploadToS3` option. However I am getting this error when using the new Amazon signature version.

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError at /admin/campaigns/1/edit_content
"\xAC" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

I have tried to change it to `getSignatureKey.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")`. After that, the server runs fine and when I upload an image I get back `SignatureDoesNotMatch` from Amazon.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Could you try the answer I posted?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but how about this?

```
kDate    = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', 'AWS4' + Figaro.env.aws_secret_access_key, Time.zone.now.utc.strftime('%Y%m%d')).encode("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8")
```

Or just

```
kDate    = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', 'AWS4' + Figaro.env.aws_secret_access_key, Time.zone.now.utc.strftime('%Y%m%d')).encode("UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ivangrx asked what I ended up doing to solve this issue. I ended up not taking this route to upload an image directly to S3. Instead I added an imageUploadURL to my froala initialization. This is a post request where I have concern doing all my work. This is what my concern looks like. I am using the updated version of the aws-sdk.

```
module Uploadable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  # NOTE: This method must be set inside all controllers that are including this module
  # This is set this way so that it will throw an exception if you forget to create the method because that would
  # silently cause the image uploading to not work correctly.
  included do
    before_action :set_image_upload_path
  end

  def upload_image
    # Setup AWS credentials
    Aws.config.update(access_key_id: Figaro.env.aws_access_key_id,
                      secret_access_key: Figaro.env.aws_secret_access_key)

    s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')

    # Prepare the necessary parameters
    bucket = if Rails.env.production?
               'app-production'
             else
               'app-dev'
             end

    # If no user, then user_id_prefix will be nil which means the user id will just not be included in the filename
    name = build_unique_filename
    file = params[:file].tempfile

    # Create the image to upload
    image = s3.bucket(bucket).object(name)

    # Upload it and respond back to Froala but respond back to Airbrake with an error message
    if image.upload_file(file, acl: 'public-read')
      render json: { link: image.public_url }
    else
      Airbrake.notify_or_ignore(error_message: 'There was a problem uploading an image to the S3 account.')
    end
  end

  def build_unique_filename
    user_id_prefix = "#{(current_user || current_admin).id}-" if current_user || current_admin

    "#{controller_name}/#{user_id_prefix}#{Time.now.to_i}-" + params[:file].original_filename
  end
end
```

This worked very well as I was able to define a different upload path for each of my resources and upload images in specific directories in my S3 bucket. If you have any questions please leave comments.